# use redisearch with openresty

Tags: redis, openresty, redisearch

I would like to use openresty to connect to [redisearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/index.html).
The are no available specific [clients](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Clients.html) for Lua, so i was thinking to use the native [lua-resty-redis](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis)

How can i execute this redis command with lua?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH myIdx "hello world" LIMIT 0 10
```

Answer (score 0):

reply  to self:

i've added this function in [redis.lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis/blob/master/lib/resty/redis.lua)

```
function _M.ftsearch(self, ...)
    return _do_cmd(self, "ft.search", ...)
end
```